# Non-Numeric Field as PK - Database Design Issue

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rdbms

I have a list of country and city names in utf8. When either list is fetched, it should return in the same order it was entered.

For example:

```
Country(country_name|PK)
City(city_name|PK, country_name|FK)
```

Country_name and city_name won't change, fixed values. However, ordering would be an issue. To make sure i retain the order values were entered as

```
Country:
UK
US
Africa
```

I added a new column called sortcountry which will numeric values from 1 and up.

```
Country(country_name|PK, sortcountry)
```

Same thing applied to City table.

I think this is a better solution than `country(country_id, countryname)`. Am i doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem addinga column for sorting if sorting doesn't follow any other natural rule.

However, you might wanna have a primary key with only sortcountry since data will be stored on disk according to it's primary/clustered index. If you normaly just select all countries then you'd want them to be read from disk in the correct order.

Then add another unique index to country_name to make sure that each name is unique (as if it where a primary key) and searchable. You would'nt want to run updates with sortcountry as your key.

Comment: It's not safe to rely on MySQL storing entries in PK order on the disk. Selecting and ordering a couple of hundred lines wouldn't normally cause a problem. I'd structure the data logically (i.e. with country_id as PK and a separate ordering column). Chances are there will be much bigger performance issues you need to optimise elsewhere in your app.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the unnecessary inner join. By doing what i just did, i can just fetch city list for each query without having to join. What an alternative would be? Assigning PK for sortcountry and then add countryname beside the sortcountry (FK)? Is it a good alternative solution? NOTE: assume sortcountry represents country_id

Answer (score 0):

"Am i doing the right thing?"

Absolutely not.

There is no inherent ordering to the results of any query.  If you want the engine to return query results in some specific order, it's your job to specify that order using the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Yes, order by sortcolumn ASC. Note that country list is not in order. Countries starting with letter A could anywhere in the list. Doing ORDER BY will sort based on letters or so which violates existent order. Anyhow, i decide to remove sortcolumn because fetching country_name as returns the list as is as long as i don't use ORDER. If you have comments, feel free to advise me.